# Number of recommendation letters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

If a department places no limit to the number of recommendation letters, how many are appropriate?

Are 5 OK? Are 7 too many?

Of course this depends on how strong the letters are - but let's assume that all of them are equally strong.

Comment: When asked for a specific number, 2-3 is common. Therefore, I would go with 2-3. Choose the strong ones among the 5-7 you could get (if I get you right). But this is just an opinion, therefore not an answer.

Comment: Did you look for similar posts on this site? Your question is similar to this one https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76601/is-having-five-letters-of-recommendation-for-stem-phd-programs-math-specifical

Comment: What country are the universities to which you are applying in?

Comment: @astronat US universities

Answer (score -1):

Go with three strong LORs like everyone else and call it good.  No one needs five and seven is ridiculous.